# I have a GregorianCalender in my entity class, how do i create an object which has specific date and display in specific format in toString()?

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat, gregorian-calendar

```
public class Book {
    Calendar dateOfPublish;

    Book(Calendar dateOfPublish, ...){}

    public Calendar getDateOfPublish() {
        return dateOfPublish;
    }

    public void setDateOfPublish(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.dateOfPublish = dateOfPublish;
    }

    public String toString() {
                return Date Of Publish=" + dateOfPublish.YEAR + "/" + dateOfPublish.MONTH + "/" + 
                       dateOfPublish.DATE;
    }
}
```

I've tried to instantiate a book object using this this as argument in the Calendar data fielld.

```
new Book(new GregorianCalendar(2018,3,20));
```

But when i display the object with toString(), it displays

```
Results:    
Date Of Publish=1/2/5
```

I've searched through internet, seeing some people use `SimpleDateFormat`, but can it be done in an entity class? Or is there any better Date/Calendar class that i should use?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your method with the completely reverse order of the parameters that you will find in the constructors of any date type available in Java.

```
public void setDateOfPublish(int day, int month, int year) {
    //...
}
```

The order of parameter in the method declaration should match with the order of arguments you pass to call it and therefore I suggest, you declare your method as follows to avoid accidents:

```
public void setDateOfPublish(int year, int month, int day) {
    //...
}
```

Also, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Using the modern date-time API, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

class Book {
    LocalDate dateOfPublish;

    // ...

    public void setDateOfPublish(LocalDate dateOfPublish) {
        this.dateOfPublish = dateOfPublish;
    }

    public void setDateOfPublish(int year, int month, int day) {
        this.dateOfPublish = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Date Of Publish=" + dateOfPublish;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setDateOfPublish(LocalDate.of(2018, 3, 20));
        System.out.println(book1);

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setDateOfPublish(2020, 2, 10);
        System.out.println(book2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Date Of Publish=2018-03-20
Date Of Publish=2020-02-10
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use new classes:

```
LocalDate dateOfPublish = LocalDate.of(2018, 03, 2);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
System.out.println(dtf.format(dateOfPublish));
```

For details refer[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Answer (score 0):

is these:

```
public String toString() {
        return "Date Of Publish = " + dateOfPublish.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " / " + dateOfPublish.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " / " +
                dateOfPublish.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Comment: It’s correct (except for the month). It’s not the recommended way to format a date into a string (better use a formatter). (And as I said elsewhere, it’s not recommended to use `GregorianCalendar` at all.) In any case thanks for your contribution.